# Block Heater Plug Location 2007 Ford Focus

Tags: ford, focus, winter

I am unable to locate the cord to plug in the block heater on my 2007 Ford Focus SES. I have not had trouble finding it on other vehicles in the past, but I have searched all over under the hood and cannot locate the plug. It's not even in the owners manual.

It's 30 below outside and I am scared to try and start it without plugging it in.

Comment: If it isn't in your manual, are you certain it has one? I have never had a car with one so this is just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

Most newer vehicles don't come with block heaters installed, so unless you've had one installed it's fairly likely that there is no block heater if you can't find a cord.

Alternatively, you could examine the oil pan for a missing cord. If you purchased the car used the previous owner may have had one installed and broke or lost the cord. I had a 2001 Saturn sedan a while back that the block heater cord had been cut off by something the previous owner had hit, I just had to buy a replacement cord and the broken one simply unplugged from the heater on the bottom of the oil pan.

Finally, if your car is having a hard time turning over you could try switching weights of oil in the winter. I used to run 10W30 in the summer months and in the fall switch to 5W30. Or you could use a synthetic blend or full synthetic motor oil. If you don't know much about lubricants I would suggest looking into them before you do this, just to make sure it won't cause any engine harm.

Edit:

I was recently browsing some forums that I read and someone mentioned something about a magnetic block heater. Apparently JC Whitney sells [this](http://www.jcwhitney.com/magnet-mount-engine-block-heater/p2000836.jcwx?filterid=u0j1) model and you can just attach it to your oil pan for heat.